# How to resolve npm peer dependency conflict

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-material, npm-install

I am upgrading from Angular 11 to Angular 14.

I have resolved all the peer dependencies except one of them.

```
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"14.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^7.2.0" from angular-tilt@1.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-tilt
npm ERR!   angular-tilt@"1.1.0" from the root project
```

How can I resolve the peer dependency `angular-tilt@1.1.0`?

[angular-tilt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tilt)

Comment: Long story short: This lib is outdated, isn't supported. I stronly advise you to not use it (it will not be compatible with Angular v16+)

Comment: Not a good idea to use that package. https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/angular-tilt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the risk of using this outdated package

you can run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`

`--legacy-peer-deps`  jumps the installation of all the peer dependencies and gives warnings about the peer deps to notice developers install them manually.